# Component will disappear when updating array in State

Tags: reactjs, next.js, html5-qrcode

I integrated [html5-qrcode](https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode) in a next.js project. The state array should be updated when barcode is recognized (`onNewScanResult`  callback).

The main code is the following. The results are logged normally but if `decodedResults` is updated, the html5-qrcode component will disappear. If I removed that line, the code would work well.

```
const [decodedResults, setDecodedResults] = useState([]);
const onNewScanResult = (decodedText, decodedResult) => {
  console.log("App [result]", decodedResult);
  setDecodedResults((prev) => [...prev, decodedResult]); // this line caused the issue
};
```

Could someone shed some light? I also created a codesanbox example here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/falling-lake-4yw25n. Just use your camera to scan some barcode or qrcode to make the component disappear.

Comment: I just tried from mobile to scan using the web version of the navigator, and it looks great for me. It's true that the log shows the array as empty, but if you do a useEffect depending on the state your updating to log it, it logs the data added correctly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/euzpO.jpg

Comment: @AlejandroOlivares What do you mean by "do a useEffect depending on the state your updating to log it"?

Comment: ```react
useEffect(() => {
    console.log({decodedResults});
}, [decodedResults])
```

Comment: @AlejandroOlivares I wrote the codesandbox url incorrectly. Now it's the next.js + html5-qrcode project. Much appreciated that you could look it again.